# How can I split text with dots delimiter when in some case there are dot delimiter that can't be separated

Tags: php, arrays, regex

Example text:

```
There is an unique news in itlogic.com. I was read it when Mrs.leafa is cooking.
```

**I want to get output like this:**

```
Array (
    [0] There is an unique news in itlogic.com.
    [1] I was read it when Mrs.leafa is cooking.
)
```

If I use `explode()` with `'.'` as the first parameter, `itlogic.com` and `Mrs.leafa` are separated.

Comment: Well, you probably can't because `Mrs.leafa` is not correct, it would be `Mrs. leafa`, unless you specify all abbreviations and ignore those when splitting.

Comment: There has to be a little bit of natural language processing for this to work correctly. Take a look at this: https://github.com/vanderlee/php-sentence

Answer (score 3):

I think `preg_split` is a good tool for this as there may or may not be a space after the dot, right?

```
$array = preg_split("/\.(?=\s|$)/m", $Text);
```

Explanation:

- `\.` Match a period
- `(?=\s|$)` Then assert a whitespace character or end of line afterwards

See here: Click on preg_split, http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/kdz

Comment: @manian As far as I know it does work. It's tested on the string.

Comment: Yes @Andreas, I think it will work. May be someone downvoted by mistake.

Comment: It works on a flawed example, but it's overly simplistic. The goal is obviously to separate sentences, and it's much more complex than this. See the comments under the question.

Comment: @manian This is what I really dislike about the downvote system. People are not forced to write a comment. I honestly think that should be a requirement for the downvote to be made.

Comment: @Don'tPanic How do you know it's flawed? Yes normally you don't write like this in text, but this may be an example? In reality it may be IP adresses for all we know.

Comment: In my opinion, it's a reasonable assumption that it's a flawed example. In my other opinion, it's wonderful that voting is anonymous and no comments are required, because it gives people the freedom to vote based on their opinion of the post without having to worry about someone complaining at them about it. People already don't vote enough as it is.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I have probably seen people give examples of apples and oranges when in reality it's something completely different they are looking for. And if the asker writes the example word.word then that is what he/she wants until something else is said. More often than even apples and oranges is that answerers assume something is wrong with the question and gives an answer to something they think is correct but is not what has been asked for. Also the downvote should be followed by a comment according to the documentation of SO if I remember correct.

Comment: "Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing."https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Answer (score 2):

try this once

```
$s= explode('. ',$your_sentence);
```

Answer (score 2):

### Update #2

Regex:

```
(?(DEFINE)          # Construct a definition structure
  (?<punc>[!?.]+)     # Define `punc` group consisting of `.`, `?` and `!`
)                   # End of definition
\b                  # Match a word boundary position
(?>                 # Open a grouping (non-capturing) (a)
  [a-z0-9]            # Match a digit or a lower case letter
  \w*                 # And any number of word characters
  |                   # Or
  [A-Z]               # Match an upper case letter
  \w{3,}              # And word characters more than 3
  (?=                 # Followed by
    (?&punc)          # Any number of `.`, `?` and `!` characters
  )                   # End of positive lookahead
)                   # End of grouping (a)
(?&punc)            # Match any number of `.`, `?` and `!` characters
\K\B\s*             # Reset match, assert a NWB position + any number of whitespaces
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/5vaxN5/4)

PHP code:

```
$str = 'There is an unique news in itlogic.com. I was read it when Mrs. leafa is cooking.';
print_r(preg_split($RE, $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => There is an unique news in itlogic.com.
    [1] => I was read it when Mrs. leafa is cooking.
)
```

Comment: This one is the best. +1 from me. @Rachmad You should accept this answer.

Comment: @Andreas, sorry I'm still failed to get output that I want with your regex code, I always get empty value in the last of element array.

Comment: @Rachmad Are you talking about my answer, or revos answer? Either way if you **always** get an empty value it's easy to handle. You can just unset the last element. Or you can test if $array($i) == "" before doing anything with the array, if you are going to loop through the array.

Comment: I talking with your answer @andreas, but I wonder why the output not same between your output and my output with your code, I use php 5.5..

Comment: @Rachmad Here, this is what I mean: https://3v4l.org/rCdM0 You can delete a empty value in an array. If you know it's always there then you can always delete it. i'ts only one line of code.